# Difference between offsetParent and parentElement or parentNode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, offset

I have a following DOM structure

```
<body>
    <div>
       <table>
          <outerElement>
              <innerElement />  
          </outerElement>
       <table>
    </div>
</body>
```

DIV has its overflow set to auto so if table grows bigger - it scrolls within the DIV.

In this scenario why `table.offsetParent` returns the body while both `table.parentNode` and `parentElement` return the Div?

I need to calculate current position of the `innerElement` within the window, so I traverse from it up thru all parent elements, collecting their `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` values. Up until the DIV `offsetParent` works fine and then it skips it directly to the body. The problem if there's scrolling involved at some point, I need to account for `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` as well - like in the DIV in the above example. The problem is if I use `offsetParent` I never encounter the DIV as one of the parents.

*UPDATE*

This is part of the code that does the traversing:

```
while (oElem && getStyle(oElem, 'position') != 'absolute' && getStyle(oElem, 'position') != 'relative') { 
   curleft += oElem.offsetLeft;
   curtop += oElem.offsetTop;
   oElem = oElem.offsetParent;
}
```

where `getStyle` is a custom function that in this case retrieves the position style.

Comment: check if you body has position:relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay clear of `offsetParent`, you'll have to add lots of hacks and checks to ensure you get it right.

Try using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) instead.

Comment: offsetParent can be very useful and used properly you will not need "lots of hacks"

Comment: @Mackelito From what I remember it has a hard time with collapsing margins, its easier to work with `getBoundingClientRect`.

Answer (score 50):

`offsetParent` is the closest parent that has `position:relative` or `position:absolute` or the body of the page. `parentNode` is the direct parent, regardless of `position`.

Comment: Not exactly, I updated the question with more details. Technically I am trying to get position of `innerElement` to be exact, and many of its parents are static.

Answer (score 4):

Using getBoudingClientRect() is really a great help (thanks Ally for the hint!).

If you still need the position relative to the upper left corner of the document, here's a helpful snippet:

```
if (node.getBoundingClientRect) {
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    var sx = -(window.scrollX ? window.scrollX : window.pageXOffset);
    var sy = -(window.scrollY ? window.scrollY : window.pageYOffset);

    return {
        x: rect.left - sx,
        y: rect.top - sy
    }
}
```

Note: `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` may return an unexpected value for `top`in Firefox under some circumstances. Therefore, the window scroll position is more robust.

For the client who do not yet support getBoundingClientRect(), we still must walk the offetParents and take care that every `overflow: scroll` (or auto) parent has `position: relative`.

Answer (score -2):

offsetParent is essentially the parent in **UI**

parentNode is actually the parent in **DATA/HTML**

offsetParent is included to deprecate traditional parentNode

Comment: welcome to stack, answer to an old question. but its answer need minimal of  stacks answer, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit you answer for give best feedback.